# All transaction should fail if at least one fails using Bulk creation for cosmos db

Tags: c#, .net, azure-cosmosdb, bulkinsert, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am inserting a list of items using bulk for cosmos db.
When one transaction fails, the others are still being created successfully. What I would like to happen is when one transaction fails all transaction should fail. So nothing should be created.

Is there a way to ensure this happens?

My code looks something like this:

```
List<Task> concurrentTasks = new List<Task>();
foreach(Item itemToInsert in ReadYourData())
{
    concurrentTasks.Add(container.CreateItemAsync(itemToInsert, new PartitionKey(itemToInsert.MyPk)));
}

await Task.WhenAll(concurrentTasks);
```

Comment: Have you read this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/transactional-outbox-cosmos

Comment: @Dai - Not true. Cosmos DB does support database transaction semantics (with some limitations, of course). Please see my answer.

Comment: @GauravMantri My favourite CosmosDB limitation is how it easy it is to accidentally get a $6,0000 Azure service charge without warning because I cranked-up a CosmosDB's performance rating for ETL and then forgot to set it back down to a far cheaper setting... fun times... (true story).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing a bulk operation, what you would need to do is perform a **transactional batch operation**. That will ensure that the whole batch will fail if one item in the batch fails.

You can learn more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/transactional-batch?tabs=dotnet.

Comment: I saw on another post that transactional batch operation are only per partition key. So cannot insert items that have different partition values in the same batch, right? In my case, the item I create partition key is the ID, meaning I can't group these togther in a transactional batch

Comment: Yeah, that’s the limitation of using transaction batch. I’m not aware of any other way to do cross-partition transactions.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the help. I will mark as anwsered

Comment: CosmosDb only supports transactions within the same partition key. If it supported transactions across partition keys, it would be a relational database, not a NoSql database.